# Bad interaction between comment package and enumerate environment?

Tags: errors, enumerate

I'm trying to use the `comment` package inside an `enumerate` environment, and it produces a compilation error. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\specialcomment{com}{}{}
\excludecomment{com}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Outside.
  \begin{com}
    Inside.
  \end{com}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

For reference, everything works fine without `enumerate`, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\specialcomment{com}{}{}
\excludecomment{com}

\begin{document}
Outside.
\begin{com}
  Inside.
\end{com}
\end{document}
```

Is this a known problem? I'm having trouble finding anything about it ("comment" isn't exactly a Google-friendly term to search for…).

Comment: Strange. If I unindent your `com` block, I don't get the error. I think you found a bug.

Comment: Page 1 of the documentation of `comment`: “The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No 
starting spaces, nothing after it.”

Comment: @hpesoj626 Oh, good catch! Similarly, it stops working when I indent the the `com` block in the working example, so it seems to be about indentation, not `enumerate`.

Comment: @egreg Ah, I read the first sentence of what you quote in the doc, but not the second… That'll teach me. Can you make that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @egreg I think that is an answer. Was it you who said looking at documentation is cheating? `;)` Or did somebody else say that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `comment` package has an important limitation; quoting from the documentation

> The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No 
>   starting spaces, nothing after it.

So there's not much more to say about it: don't indent the environment that you want to "comment out".

Here's a different implementation; I've left the same syntax for `\specialcomment` with three arguments, although nothing is done with the second and third (it can be improved for using them).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}

\newcommand\specialcomment[3]{%
  \newtoggle{#1}\toggletrue{#1}
  \NewEnviron{#1}{\iftoggle{#1}{\BODY}{}}
}
\newcommand{\excludecomment}[1]{\togglefalse{#1}}
\newcommand{\includecomment}[1]{\toggletrue{#1}}

\specialcomment{com}{}{}
\excludecomment{com} 

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Outside.
  \begin{com}
    Inside.
  \end{com}
\item Outside. Inside.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for "The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it."